# Is there a way to get the variables for a Bitbucket pipeline using Bitbucket API?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a pipeline which is taking some input variables like name, description. These variables are configured manually before every pipeline run.

I need these specific inputs using Bibucket API. From the following documentation https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pipelines/, I don't see any method to get the variables used to build the pipeline.

Getting the information for a single pipeline doesn't help. This is the API call for a specific pipeline [https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pipelines/{pipeline_uuid}](https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pipelines/%7Bpipeline_uuid%7D)

Does anybody know if there is a way to access these inputs using Bitbucket API?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to get the variables passsed to the pipeline you trigger.you can save them in other places,for example,redis hashset,mysql table when you triggering pipelines.